# How to apply a text file with multiple variables to the batch console

Tags: variables, batch-file, console, command

Okay so I have a batch program that writes my character's stats to a txt file when I save the game. However I am unable to load those stats properly. I thought maybe if I saved them with console commands and syntax properly that I could use the type command and it would run the commands setting the variables on the console to the ones in the txt file. Is there a simple way just like writing all of the variables to the txt file but reverse?

Sample code of variables being written:

```
if not exist "%~dp0\Users" md "Users" (
Echo set CharName=%UserCharacter%
Echo set Level=%Level%
Echo set Health=%Health%
Echo set ExpCap=%ExpCap%
)> "%~dp0\Users\%UserCharacter%.txt"
```

See I wrote it like this to the text file thinking I could load the file and it would set the variables to what the file had.

Didn't work. If you have any questions ask. I can't post pictures right now but I think I got my point across.

Comment: Isn't there a line-break or a `&` missing in your code snippet (after the `md` command)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close. Instead of `type`, run the text file through a for loop.

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%~dp0\Users\%UserCharacter%.txt") do %%A
```

The `set` commands you have will automatically run.

**How It Works**
A `for /f` loop takes in a command, file, or string (in this case, a file) and processes the output of that thing line by line.

The `usebackq` tells the `for` loop that the thing in quotes is a file - ordinarily, a quoted string passed into a `for /f` loop would be treated as a string instead, but since you have a space in your path, that needs to be quoted so that the loop doesn't throw an error.

`delims=` tells the loop not to delimit (split) each line in the file. Ordinarily, a line is split on whitespace - spaces and tabs.

`%%A` is the variable containing the first delimited token in the string. However, since we told the loop not to delimit the string, `%%A` contains the entire string.

`"%~dp0\Users\%UserCharacter%.txt"` is your file.

`do` tells the loop that everything after this for the rest of the code block (either the rest of the line or anything between a `(` on that line and the first  `)` on a lower line) should be performed while the loop is still ongoing.

`%%A` in this case is the `set` command you have stored in your text file. Because of how batch replaces and evaluates text, it is actually running the commands you have stored!

Comment: Awesome, can you explain in depth how this works? The syntax that is, if not that's okay just would like to know the underlying workings of what I'm typing. I understand the for part but don't really get the "usebackq delims=" or the %%A

Comment: For more info on the FOR /F command and its options, nothing beats the [original documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can save your variables with the following batch file:

```
@Echo off

if not exist "Users" md "Users"
if exist Users\%UserCharacter%.bat del Users\%UserCharacter%.bat
>>Users\%UserCharacter%.bat Echo @Echo off
>>Users\%UserCharacter%.bat Echo set CharName=%UserCharacter%
>>Users\%UserCharacter%.bat Echo set Level=%Level%
>>Users\%UserCharacter%.bat Echo set Health=%Health%
>>Users\%UserCharacter%.bat Echo set ExpCap=%ExpCap%
>>Users\%UserCharacter%.bat Echo Echo Variables loaded

Echo Variables saved
```

This creates a batch file named **%UserCharacter%.bat** in the *Users* subfolder.
And if, for instance, your character name is Virtusal, you would then load those variables back by typing **Users\Virtusal.bat**.

Comment: I like this way as well more so than the legit but more so because I understand it. Thank you for the work around my friend.

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted then, as I am new to participating on this site and trying to build a reputation.